# Selectable Variable/goto statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

so i am making a basic dice game for school - i am very new to this. basically what i want is to be able to have upto 3 dice being rolled but would like each to run a different code (to be rolling 1/2/3 dice) 
i had something like this but found out there is no "goto" statement

```
Dice = input("Please select number of dice you would like to use (1-3)") #20
    if Dice == "1":
        print("You have selected 1 dice")

elif Dice == "2":
    print("You have selected 2 dice")

elif Dice == "3":
    print("You have selected 3 dice")

elif Dice == "":
    print ("\n" "Please Select number of dice you wish to use (Select a number between 1 and 3)")
```

what should i either do or how would i make this go to a specific place in the code to run what i have next.

Comment: There's no `elif` statement either, in JavaScript it is `else if`, and the `if`/`else if` conditions need to be in parentheses with no colon after them. And what are `input()` and `print()`? Are you sure you put the right tag on this question?

Comment: What language are you using. It looks nothing like JavaScript

Comment: @DanPhilip It looks like python

Comment: i am using python

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will want to use a while loop. They look something like this:

```
while (condition):
    #do stuff
```

Assuming that the user will only enter a valid integer then your code could look something like this:

```
while True:
    dice = int(input("Enter the number of dice you would like to roll. (between 1 and 3) -> "))
    if (dice >= 1 and dice <= 3):
        #more checks here if you like
        #And make sure you 'break' or this will be an infinite loop
```

Sorry if my Python syntax is a bit off, haven't done it for a while. Hope this helps, if you have any questions please feel free to ask!

Happy coding!

Comment: thankyou, do you have any idea what i could use for a scoring system,

Comment: @CarlThompson Can you explain what you want your scoring system to be like? UI, requirements?

Comment: something like everytime player 1 wins they get +1 points then at the end when they want to reveal scores their score is submitted